# Including responsive styles in main stylesheet - overriding main styles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

Rather than having one huge responsive.css files. I am including the media queries in the same stylsheet to keep everything together, for example i have wizard.css file, with:

```
 span.crumbsTxt {
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 16px;
   line-height: 1.25em;
 }
```

Then at the bottom of the same wizard.css file, i have:

```
    /* col-sm - Small tablets */
    @media (min-width: 768px){
         span.crumbsTxt {
         font-size: 14px;
       }
    }
```

The issue i am having is that all my styles from the media queries are overriding my original styles, even when it doesn't hit the small screen media query.

So in this example i am on a large screen, but for some reason its using all my styles from the media query!

I don't want to use !important, but don't understand why its doing this as it's breaking my whole site!

Thanks

EDIT:
Is my media query setup wrong then - what needs to change?

Are my media queries wrong then, what needs to change to avoid my issues? :-

```
 /* col-xs - mobile screens */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

 /* col-sm - Small tablets */
 @media (min-width: 768px) {}

 /* col-md - Medium screens */
 @media (min-width: 992px) {}

 /* col-lg - Large Desktop screens */
 @media (min-width: 1250px) {}
```

Seems that my bootstrap.min.css uses min width as well. Any ideas on how i could change the above media queries to solve the overriding issue i am having?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `max-width` instead of `min-width` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `min-width` to `max-width` 
You can also apply a `min-width` and `max-width`

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 420px) 
and (max-device-width : 780px)
```

Also, keep in mind that if two selectors apply to the same element, the one with **higher specificity wins**.

Comment: Thanks, i have added my media queries into the original question at the top, any advice on whats wrong here would be great.

Comment: I'd advice starting from bigger screens to smaller screens, and using `MAX-width` instead of `MIN-width` so it overrides better, So start with the normal CSS at top, then the biggest query, and then the smaller quearies

Comment: so have normal css, then order the media queries large / medium / small / x-small? The only bit im struggling with is how to change my media queries from min-width to use max-width with the correct sizes??

Comment: @John That's correct, just order your css file code from base css, big mediaqueries to smaller ones, change min-width to max-width and you're done.

Comment: what about the values of screen sizes? will these need to change?

Comment: @John You choose use the values yourself, you just have to follow the queries order and you're fine.

Comment: i guess if i kept the same values ive used it would not work correctly? sorry mate im new to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63929/discussion-between-nick-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 780px) 
{
    .class
    {
        styles
    }
}
```

When you use this code everything restyles when the screen is SMALLER as 780px.
But when you use min-width everything restyles when the screen is BIGGER as 780px

Comment: Thanks, i have added my media queries into the original question at the top, any advice on whats wrong here would be great.

Comment: Try this:  @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {       span.crumbsTxt {
         font-size: 14px;
       }}

Comment: The thing is: You have to set which needs to change at the screen size of 768.. So if you want the font-size of the class span.crumbsTxt to change, add it in your media query with the sizing of max-width: 767.

Answer (score -1):

you are write the min width in your media query and it can not write in max width.so give the max width also after that check.

@media (min-width:800px) and (max-width:767px){

}